# php - hacer un autocompletado con PHP, MySQL y Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando hacer un autocompletado con jquery, y he encontrado muchos tutoriales, los cuales algunos me funcionan, pero a nivel de diseño me gustaría hacerlo Bootstrap... por el tema del responsive mas que nada.
Algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? Algún ejemplo? Espero me disculpen, pero soy nuevo en PHP.

Comment: Hay muchísimas opciones, tan solo es buscar en google. Sugeriría que no uses jQuery UI autocomplete, a menos que aproveches jquery UI de otra manera, prueba con librerías más sencillas como (http://easyautocomplete.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para usar bootstrap con jquery podrías hacer algo así:

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
    "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran",
    "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl",
    "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
  ];
  
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Languages</label>
    <input class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Enter A" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >Another Field</label>
    <input class="form-control">
  </div>

</div>
```

Respuesta obtenida de SO en Inglés, en el siguiente link a la pregunta puedes encontrar más formas de hacerlo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285813/style-jquery-autocomplete-in-a-bootstrap-input-field